# What does it mean to share an implementation?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, implementation, shared

As the title notes I'm looking to understand what does it mean to share an implementation. To be more specific, I want to know **HOW** it works. I get what the words mean but I'm not clear on the process of how it works.

Ex. "The fast-enumeration implementation is shared between the Objective-C runtime and the Foundation framework."

This is from Apple's Cocoa Fundamentals doc. I was reading and came across this line and am trying to understand the process.

Thanks

Comment: It probably means that it is implemented in the Objective-C runtime, in the Foundation library, and perhaps even in the Objective-C compiler...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This basically covers a somewhat contradictional programming pattern (which, in my opinion, is wrong): the Objective-C language, the `libobjc` runtime library and the Foundation framework aren't strictly separated. For example, some fundamental message names, such as `retain`, `release`, etc. are hard-coded into the Objective-C runtime library (e. g., in order ARC to recognize these as special memory management-related messages), and this is the case with the fast enumeration as well.

The `countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:` selector is recognized by the compiler, and it is emitted when the `for (object in collection)` syntax is encountered. Then the collection object, of which the class implements this hard-wired message of the protocol `NSFastEnumeration`, updates `count`, `objects`, its return value, etc. according to how the runtime library and the ABI expects it.

For historical reasons, there's such a tight coupling between these three things (the language/the compiler, the runtime library and the Foundation framework) that this hard-coding approach is usable and realistic, but it's also a *terrible violation* of separation of the language and the library. I even dare to say that this is a **quite dirty hack.**

Comment: I'm not sure it is such an *ugly* hack (it is a *dirty* hack, not really an ugly one). The only way to avoid that hack would be (like Lisp, Smalltalk do...) to have the runtime, the foundation, and the compiler be one single product & program. Do you really want that?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm not a native English speaker, excuse me for that. I've just updated the terminology according to your comment.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch As for the solution: no, what you proposed isn't the only solution. If there were: 1. compiler switches to specify memory management and fast enumeration selector names, object literal classes (there is one for string literals, `-fconstant-string-class`), etc. **and** it was also possible to tell the runtime using some setting functions what these are (or even better, let the compiler generate these calls), that would be the proper solution.

Comment: I'm not neither a native English speaker.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Whatever, you were right in the terminology.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I think you mean API not ABI.

Comment: @Tremaine No, I mean ABI, not API. Google it. If I meant API, I should have rectified so as to make it clear which API I am talking about. However, there are only one ABI for each platform (that is, hardware and OS architecture).

Comment: Even further, [as of 10.8, NSObject itself is in libobjc](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15458992/30461).